# $emit on global bus inside setTimeout making unresponsive page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a global eventbus on Vue2. The event is catched by a child component and it shows a bootstrap popup modal dialog.

Emit:

```
mounted: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.showInfoDialog();
    }, 3000);
},
...
showInfoDialog: function() {
        eventBus.$emit('showInfoDialog');
        this.infoDialogDisplayed = true;
}
```

The event listener on child component looks like:

```
created: function() {
    eventBus.$on('showInfoDialog', this.onShowDialog);
},
...
onShowDialog: function() {
    $('#info-modal').modal('show');
},
```

After showing the dialog I'm getting a "Unresponsive page" alert that happens sometimes (its not repeatable).

Should the $emit be called inside a $nextTick? What could be the problem?

Comment: Try adding log-comments to the functions to see if anything are called more than expected.

Comment: What's the relationship between the two sections of code you've shown. Is it all on one component? Or separate components?

Comment: Thanks @d00dle you hit the problem, the interval gets executed 3 times! Any clue on what can it be?

Comment: @thanksd they are two different components... the one that resolves the dialog show is a child one.

Comment: @jigarzon I assume that this code is in a component. Could it be as simple as this module is loaded multiple times (maybe even from another function)?

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank every comment. It had nothing to do with Vue.JS or Javascript. The problem was with another library I was using that was hanging the page because it was dispatched when the dialog was closed.